# after setting LDAP in WAS for maximo i cant see maximousers in manage groups

Tags: websphere, maximo

after setting up LDAP in WAS maximousers is not create in manage group and when i want to create the group i get this error

CWWIM4520E The 'javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - 00000005: SecErr: DSID-03152612, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0 ]; remaining name 'cn=s,OU=MAXIMO,DC=CTS,DC=com'; resolved object com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@ecfb5e99' naming exception occurred during processing

is this a binding issue ?

Comment: `INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS` - user that is used to bind to LDAP doesnt have rights to create objects.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to update the file wimconfig.xml located in /config/cells//wim/config/ because this vakue : "'cn=s,OU=MAXIMO,DC=CTS,DC=com'" is not correct

cf. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21368224